# How to install PyQt5 in Python 3 (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, pyqt5

I need to port some code that's Python2+PyQt4 to Python3+PyQt5.

I started installing pip3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Works great. Tried

```
sudo pip3 install PyQt5
Downloading/unpacking PyQt5
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PyQt5
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for PyQt5
```

Online I find the following steps:

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html

But they are too many. What's the easiest way to Install PyQt5 along with Python3 in Ubuntu 14.04 ?

Comment: pip install pyqt5 worked just fine

Comment: The install process went ok. But got runtime error QtCore.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_AdjustIndices

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Why not simply install it via apt-get?

```bash
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

Otherwise you'd have to compile PyQt (and potentially Qt) by hand, which is cumbersome.

Comment: I didn't knew it was possible.

Comment: This command is installing python3.4, how can i get python3.7?

Comment: [See here for the Python2 command as well as the Python3 command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36806286/4561887)

Answer (score 26):

Well I documented the steps for Installing pyqt5 with qt designer and code generation here: https://gist.github.com/1dcd57542bdaf3c9d1b0dd526ccd44ff

### Installation

```
pip3 install --user pyqt5  
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5  
sudo apt-get install pyqt5-dev-tools
sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools
```

### Configuring to run from terminal

```
$ qtchooser -run-tool=designer -qt=5
```

**OR**

Write the following in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf`

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

### Code Generation

Create uic.py file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess
import sys

child = subprocess.Popen(['pyuic5' ,'-x',sys.argv[1]],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

print(str(child.communicate()[0],encoding='utf-8'))
```

---

```
$ chmod +x uic.py
```

**Create a symlink:**

```
$ sudo ln uic.py "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/uic"
```

### Desktop Entry

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Qt5 Designer
Icon=designer
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/designer
Type=Application
Categories=Application
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Actions=NewWindow

Name[en_US]=Qt5 Designer

[Desktop Action NewWindow]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/designer
```

**save in ~/.local/share/application with .desktop extension**

Comment: `pip3 install --user pyqt5` will most likely throw `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sip>=4.19.1`. I'm installing it from a fresh Linux installation.

Comment: where are you putting the uic.py file?

Answer (score 0):

- sudo apt-get install python3-pip
- sudo pip3 install PyQt5

Answer (score 0):

### How to install PyQt5 in Python3

*Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.*

Just installing it did *not* work for me. I had to *uninstall* it first, then reinstall it:

```bash
# upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

# uninstall
python3 -m pip uninstall PyQt5
python3 -m pip uninstall PyQt5-sip
python3 -m pip uninstall PyQtWebEngine

# reinstall
python3 -m pip install PyQt5
python3 -m pip install PyQt5-sip
python3 -m pip install PyQtWebEngine
```

See here for my full answer, including how to install it for a specific version of Python3, such as Python3.8: [How to install PyQt5 in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74465762/4561887)