# Python 3.7.0 No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have Python 3.7.0 and I installed PyQt5 with this command:

```
pip install PyQt5
```

I have returned this error:

```
    main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'
```

In Eclipse I have this configuration:

[image]

What may be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Your system is 32 bits?

Comment: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5, Note that for v5.11 and later the 32-bit Windows wheels do not contain the WebEngine modules. and Wheels are provided for Python v3.5 and later for 64-bit Linux, macOS and 32-bit and 64-bit Windows. These include copies of the corresponding Qt libraries.

Comment: Use a final version of Python to solve this problem.

Comment: which kind of python version I have to install for install with pip all the requirements?

Comment: Having the same issue - does this mean that the 32 Bit Windows doesn't come with QtWebEngineWidgets when installing PyQt?

Comment: I have the same issue too and I didn't find solution. Is there a solution that has been found?

Answer (score 114):

**It has been moved to a separated package.**

Based on this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763612/importerror-no-module-named-pyqt5-qtwebenginewidgets) and my own experience,
Just execute in a terminal:

```
pip install PyQtWebEngine
```

If you still got problems with PyQt, try uninstalling all of the PyQt related libraries:

```
pip uninstall PyQt5
pip uninstall PyQt5-sip
pip uninstall PyQtWebEngine
```

Then install them again, which should fix the following errors:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.sip'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'
```

If you got problems uninstalling the libraries, go to your Python folder, like:

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python<PYTHON-VERSION>\Lib\site-packages
```

and manually delete the PyQt folders, then uninstall everything and install again. **Make sure you have the latest Python version and have upgraded your pip too.**

```bash
# install latest python version for your operating system, then
# upgrade pip:
pip install --upgrade pip

# uninstall everything
pip uninstall PyQt5
pip uninstall PyQt5-sip
pip uninstall PyQtWebEngine

# install everything
pip install PyQt5
pip install PyQt5-sip
pip install PyQtWebEngine
```

Comment: It looks like the pip package for Spyder on Python 3.6 doesn't install this automatically for some reason, there might be a bug in that package since it seems like PyQtWebEngine is required for Spyder to run.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me on Manjaro 64 bit, with a PyQt 5.12.1 installed via `pip`

Comment: `Command "/Users/admin/NoteMngr/bin/python /Users/admin/NoteMngr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/v8/hfj_m1rj2ss7b0zcfgsppz5m0000gn/T/tmpcs9lnxeb" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/v8/hfj_m1rj2ss7b0zcfgsppz5m0000gn/T/pip-install-ou3rfj3r/PyQtWebEngine`

Comment: ...and don't forget to reboot the system after that! [same issue on Linux at least debian & manjaro and solved as in the answer + reboot]

Comment: For PyQt6 the package is renamed to `PyQt6-WebEngine`

Comment: I had a problem uninstalling the packages, so I had to _remove the **dist-info** folder_ of PyQt5 and PyQtWebEngine from `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/` directory (for linux users) before I could reinstall the packages.

Answer (score 10):

For me, *first uninstalling* PyQtWebEngine with
`pip uninstall PyQtWebEngine`
and *then reinstalling* with 
`pip install PyQtWebEngine`
solved the problem of Spyder not starting.

Answer (score 3):

I have just installed older version of pyqt5

```
pip install PyQt5==5.7.1
```

Answer (score 3):

this is a problem with pyqt5.
You can try:

```
pip install pyqt5==pyqt5.8
```

or same for conda

Answer (score 1):

For `PyQt6`, these packages needs to be installed.

```
PyQt6==6.5.0
PyQt6-Qt6==6.5.0
PyQt6-sip==13.5.0
PyQt6-WebEngine==6.5.0
PyQt6-WebEngine-Qt6==6.5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Run your terminal as administrator and install pyqt5 and PyQtWebEngine from there, it usually works if you are using anaconda for example and if not installing in your current env.

```
python -m pip install PyQt5
python -m pip install PyQtWebEngine
```

You may need to import your module and submodules depending on your code.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
```

If it doesn't work try to push up your current env in the windows env config and try to reinstall pyqt5 .

[image]