# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am using pycharm and python 3.7 and I have installed PyQt5 
When using this snippet

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebPage
```

I got an error:
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebPage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'

Any ideas how to fix that error..?

I have downloaded PyQt5_gpl-5.10
and this is snapshot of the downloaded files
[image]

How can I install those files in pycharm? from local path?

I am newbie to python so please give me detailed steps if possible
Regards

Comment: 32 bits or 64 bits?

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51154871/python-3-7-0-no-module-named-pyqt5-qtwebenginewidgets

Comment: @ eyllanesc : Windows 7 32 Bit

Comment: Read https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5 : *Note that for v5.11 and later the 32-bit Windows wheels do not contain the WebEngine modules.*

Comment: so use an old version of PyQt5, or use a 64bit PC or compile QtWebEngine manualement for 32 bits (the latter is a heavy and tedious task if you are a beginner)

Comment: Thanks a lot for great help. Can you give me a link to older version that would work for me .. as I have searched and lost in fact

Comment: as indicated by the docs with PyQt 5.9 or PyQt 5.10 should work

Comment: So what ..? Can you provide me with a link to this working version?

Comment: use pip: `pip install pyqt5==5.10`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's greta. How about pycharm..? How can I use pip install in pycharm .. Sorry for my trivial questions(that's because I am so beginner)

Comment: Using pycharm as shown in the following tutorial you can choose the version of the library you want. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't get a clue>> I have installed pyqt5 in pycharm (not 5.10) as it doesn't exist when searching inside pycharm. Will I uninstall the version I installed? How can I install the file I downloaded in main post of this thread (There's snapshot)

Answer (score 1):

You should install older version not the latest one

pip install PyQt5==5.7.1