# How to have plotly graph as PyQt5 widget?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am doing GUI where there should be a widget with the following plot:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.box(df, x="day", y="total_bill", color="smoker")
fig.update_traces(quartilemethod="exclusive") # or "inclusive", or "linear" by default
fig.show()
```

Can you suggest something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a `QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView` widget to show the figure. You might need to install the `PyQtWebEngine` package first. Here is a small example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
import plotly.express as px


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Plot', self)
        self.browser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self)

        vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.browser)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.show_graph)
        self.resize(1000,800)

    def show_graph(self):
        df = px.data.tips()
        fig = px.box(df, x="day", y="total_bill", color="smoker")
        fig.update_traces(quartilemethod="exclusive") # or "inclusive", or "linear" by default
        self.browser.setHtml(fig.to_html(include_plotlyjs='cdn'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Thanks Heike, I ran it and got and error of ImportError: QtWebEngineWidgets must be imported before a QCoreApplication instance is created. any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: It looks like you are initialising the `QApplication` instance before importing `QtWebEngineWidgets`

Comment: right Heike, but how to change your code to make it work? I used the same code as you shown above.  I even move from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets to beforeapp = QtWidgets.QApplication([]) inside if __name__ == "__main__":, and it still not working? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54947671/3059024