# how to embedd plotly graph in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, spyder, plotly-python, qwebengineview

I googled and found two codes and I got same below error. any can help?

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

ImportError: QtWebEngineWidgets must be imported before a QCoreApplication instance is created
```

1st code:
https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/716

```
import plotly.offline as po
import plotly.graph_objs as go

from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys


def show_qt(fig):
    raw_html = '<html><head><meta charset="utf-8" />'
    raw_html += '<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script></head>'
    raw_html += '<body>'
    raw_html += po.plot(fig, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')
    raw_html += '</body></html>'

    fig_view = QWebEngineView()
    # setHtml has a 2MB size limit, need to switch to setUrl on tmp file
    # for large figures.
    fig_view.setHtml(raw_html)
    fig_view.show()
    fig_view.raise_()
    return fig_view


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    fig = go.Figure(data=[{'type': 'scattergl', 'y': [2, 1, 3, 1]}])
    fig_view = show_qt(fig)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

2nd code:

[How to have plotly graph as PyQt5 widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60522103/how-to-have-plotly-graph-as-pyqt5-widget/60523577?noredirect=1#comment122396125_60523577)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
import plotly.express as px


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Plot', self)
        self.browser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self)

        vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.browser)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.show_graph)
        self.resize(1000,800)

    def show_graph(self):
        df = px.data.tips()
        fig = px.box(df, x="day", y="total_bill", color="smoker")
        fig.update_traces(quartilemethod="exclusive") # or "inclusive", or "linear" by default
        self.browser.setHtml(fig.to_html(include_plotlyjs='cdn'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Are you using any special environment? I do not get that warning

Comment: Hi eyllanesc, yes in anaconda, I use an environment and run the code under the environment. how do I know what inside this environment cause this issue?

Comment: Well, do not use anaconda and if you see that this error does not reproduce then you already know who is the culprit :-).

Comment: Thanks eyllanesc. Inside same enviroment, I switch to use jupyter notebook, then all these 2 codes are working fine.  I was using spyder 5. so the problem is from spyder. do you know any solution? Thanks

Comment: No, report it to spyder. But I would not worry since it is only a warning, spyder probably creates a QXApplication that is not compatible with the one you use in your script.

Comment: no, it is not just a warning. my pyqt5 app cannot be launched. Thanks

Comment: So just don't use spyder.

Comment: yes it is spyder issue. I ran py file directly inside anaconda command prompt by using python file.py, and it works. Thanks