# Using plotly with pyqt5

Tags: python, plot, pyqt5, plotly

I am trying to use plotly with pyqt5. I found an example code here: [How to have plotly graph as PyQt5 widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60522103/how-to-have-plotly-graph-as-pyqt5-widget)
The code is the following:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
import plotly.express as px


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Plot', self)
        self.browser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self)

        vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.browser)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.show_graph)
        self.resize(1000,800)

    def show_graph(self):
        df = px.data.tips()
        fig = px.box(df, x="day", y="total_bill", color="smoker")
        fig.update_traces(quartilemethod="exclusive") # or "inclusive", or "linear" by default
        self.browser.setHtml(fig.to_html(include_plotlyjs='cdn'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```

When I try to run it, I get the following error messege:

```
[18152:16788:0924/110112.767:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1399)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary: mf.dll: The specified module could not be found. (0x7E)
[18152:16788:0924/110112.770:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1399)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary: mfplat.dll: The specified module could not be found. (0x7E)
[18152:16788:0924/110112.771:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1399)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary: msmpeg2vdec.dll: The specified module could not be found. (0x7E)
[18152:16788:0924/110112.773:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1407)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary: msvproc.dll: The specified module could not be found. (0x7E)
```

What could I do?

Comment: Do you have an “N” version of Windows?

Comment: Yes, Windows 10 Education N.

Comment: You need to download "Windows Media Feature Pack": https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack

Comment: Thanks for the help, it did not work, but I found an other way.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to install the windows media feature pack as @tromgy suggested, but apparently "These changes are not applicable" to my PC, so I downloaded the dll-s one by one from https://www.dll-files.com/ and pasted them to C:\Windows\System32, and now the code works.