# QtWebEngineWidgets in virtualenv: ImportError: libQt5QmlModels.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyqt5, virtualenv

I'm working on a computer with CentOS 8. To execute a python module, I've created a virtual environment with `python3.9 -m venv venv`  and activated it with `source venv/bin/activate`. After installing the dependencies with `pip 21.3.1`, I'm getting the following error when I try to import `QtWebEngineWidgets`.

```
(venv) [user@localhost myprog]$ python3 -c "from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libQt5QmlModels.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, when I look in the `site-packages` directory of the virtual environment, the file exists.

```
(venv) [user@localhost myprog]$ find venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/* -name "libQt5QmlModels*"
venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/libQt5QmlModels.so.5
venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/qt5_applications/Qt/lib/libQt5QmlModels.so.5
```

The output using `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1" is the same as without:

```
(venv) [user@localhost myprog]$ QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 python3 -c "from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libQt5QmlModels.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Further details:

- If I install the modules `PyQt5`, `PyQt5-sip` and `QtWebEngineWidgets` outside of the virtual environment, the import works without problems (outside of the venv).
- Using other python versions for the virtual environment (tested: 3.6, 3.8) the problem doesn't appear either

What am I doing wrong? Why can't the `libQt5QmlModels.so.5` be found?

I've read a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51154871/python-3-7-0-no-module-named-pyqt5-qtwebenginewidgets) with the same title but it didn't help, since I've already installed/upgraded the modules listed in the solution.

Comment: execute `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 python3 -c "from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets"`

Comment: @eyllanesc The output is the same as without, I've updated the question with that info