# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5' - Windows PyCharm

Tags: python, pip, pyqt, pyqt5

I pip installed PyQt5, and verified this in my CMD with `pip show PyQt5` which gave me:

```
C:\Users\92175>pip show PyQt5
Name: PyQt5
Version: 5.15.0
Summary: Python bindings for the Qt cross platform application toolkit
Home-page: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/
Author: Riverbank Computing Limited
Author-email: info@riverbankcomputing.com
License: GPL v3
Location: c:\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages
Requires: PyQt5-sip
Required-by:
```

When I run my code in PyCharm, `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui...`  I get the error
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'`

I saw the same question in another place: [ImportError: No module named PytQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672918/importerror-no-module-named-pytqt5) however this is a little different since I'm neither using Ubuntu nor `bash`.

Do I need to bother my IT guy and ask him to help me modify `PYTHONPATH`? (I think admin rights are required for this). If so, how should I do this? Or is there a way to direct PyCharm to the location of PyQt5 from within my code?

Comment: It's all okay. It's saying that you don't have "location" package. `pip show` tries to find package `location` first - you dont have it, then it lists `pyqt5`

Comment: Are you sure pycharm is using the python where you installed pyqt5?

Comment: @eyllanesc great question. I will try to find that out!

Comment: @eyllanesc -- so I went to PyCharm > Settings > Project > Project Interpreter > +Package > searched for and selected PyQt5 and clicked `Install Package` > Which gave me an error: `Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pyqt5/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: ...` PyCharm also suggested: "Try to run this command from the system terminal." which I already did. What should I try now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize it at first, but this question is really about PyCharm packages.

**Solution:**

1. PyCharm > File > Settings
2. Project > click `+` to add package
3. type PyQt5

Make sure your proxy settings are correct (mine weren't at first). Now it's working.
If you need a proxy:

1. PyCharm > File > Settings
2. Version Control > Subversion > Network > Navigate to general proxy settings
3. Check `automatic` or `manual` and fill in details > OK