# Python3 Modules not loading on other computers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been coding an python application in *PyCharm* and I have had an issue when trying to run to program on other devices. When cloning the repo on my laptop I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matthew/PycharmProjects/HealthTrackerForRachel/Main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

I have done `pip install PyQt5` on my current computer so it should have the module. I am also using venv so could this be causing an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has to do with installing PyQts5. here the question was answered already [ImportError: No module named PytQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672918/importerror-no-module-named-pytqt5).