# PyQt 5.3.1 Installing on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, pyqt5

I am trying to build PyQt 5.3.1 on ubuntu 14.04. I need QtWebKit module on it.

I configured it following step

```
python configure.py -q /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake --sip-incdir=/usr/include/python2.7 --sipdir=/usr/share/sip  --enable QtWebKit QtWebKitWidgets
```

I got following error when I am using `make`,

```
$HOME/PyQt-gpl-5.3.1/QtWebKit/sipQtWebKitQWebSettings.cpp:1208:48: error: ‘WebAudioEnabled’ is not a member of ‘QWebSettings’
     {sipName_WebAudioEnabled, static_cast<int>(QWebSettings::WebAudioEnabled), 26},
                                            ^
make[1]: *** [sipQtWebKitQWebSettings.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '$HOME/PyQt-gpl-5.3.1/QtWebKit'
make: *** [sub-QtWebKit-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems [helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698877/fatal-error-while-compiling-pyqt5-python-h-does-not-exist)!

Comment: Alternatively, you can install it with `apt-get install python3-pyqt5`.

Answer (score 0):

you can install PyQt5 with `pip` instead of building from source.
try `pip install Python-Qt5`